# Class syntax cannot access variable properly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class

I'm learning the class syntax in javascript. I'm trying to define a class, which holds a person's first and last name, tardies and absence count. The tardies and the absences are automatically set to 0 on instance initialization. Below is my code with a function that adds tardies and prints the amount of tarides:

```
class Student{
    construtor(firstName,secondName){
        this.firstName=firstName;
        this.secondName=secondName;
        this.tardies=0;
        this.absences=0;
    }
    IncreaseTardies () {
      this.tardies+=1
        return this.tardies;
    }
}

//Test
let Sample = new Student("A","B");
//Output undefined
Sample.IncreaseTardies()
//Output NaN
//Expected output 1
```

The code doesn't seem to work as intended since it returns NaN instead of the value+1 when IncreaseTardies() is called. I tried placing a console.log inside the constructor, which gave no result at all and adding breakpoints with identical success. What is the error in my code that prevents it from increasing the number of tardies?

Comment: `"construtor" !== "constructor"`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a typo in the constructor function as a name. Thanks to jonrsharpe for pointing out the issue.

The working code is:

```
class Student{
    constructor(firstName,secondName){
        this.firstName=firstName;
        this.secondName=secondName;
        this.tardies=0;
        this.absences=0;
    }
    IncreaseTardies () {
      this.tardies+=1
        return this.tardies;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spelling of constructor is not correct, Please change it to **constructor** from **construtor**, Here **c** is missing... :)